# Selectively hide or show certain PDF content over email

Tags: pdf, itext

I recently received a PDF file from my bank that had many details along with my account number. I wanted to share the PDF with one of my relatives, I immediately forwarded the PDF to him. To my surprise he was not able to see my account number in the PDF, that I was able to see.

Immediately I opened my sent items folder and tried to open the PDF from the sent mail. And to my surprise I was not able to the see the account number there also.

The account number text was visible only when I opened PDF attachment from the original mail. This has gotten me all curious.

Does someone know anything about a mechanism on how to achieve this? How can I do this using itextsharp or a similar library.

Thanks

Amar

Comment: I work at iText. We are more than happy to have a look at it. Some of us think it's being done with javascript. Some of us think it's DRM. Could you send us the file? We'll handle it confidentially of course.
Or provide us with your contact details. This case certainly has our interest!

Comment: Email us at community@itextpdf.com